# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jquery')

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm getting this error when using bootstrap@4.6.2 in react js application.

I've already installed jquery.

Imported the bootstrap bundle as

```
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";
```

but it throws `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jquery')`

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by dynamically importing the bootstrap module inside `useEffect`

inside `app.ts`

```
useEffect(() => {
    require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle");
  }, []);
```